# tsql wait for change with Read Committed Snapshot On

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, isolation-level, read-committed-snapshot

Hi Stackoverflow community,

Let me ask for your help as I did run into a critical issue.

We have two linked servers and both are Microsoft SQL Servers: CRM and DW servers. Some changes in **CRM system** triggers a procedure to instantly get updates to DW server, and the way it works is that **CRM system** calls DW server to update the record. In my case the updates coming from **CRM system** for CRM and DW sql servers are **called simultaneous**, and here the problem begins.

DW server tries to read changes and gets records **only** before transaction begin. Yes, this happens because CRM Server uses:

> Read Committed Snapshot On

**Unfortunately,** we are not able to change isolation level on the CRM sql server. Simple explanation- CRM comes from a third party provider, and they want to limit us to make these possibilities.

**Is there any other way, to wait for transaction to commit and then read the latest data after commitment?**

If there is a lack of information, please let me know, then I will provide more insights.

Comment: you tagged two different versions of SQL Server, not sure if this was intended with the two CRM and DW servers, but I added the sql-server tage instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the control flow here, but from the first paragraph you said updates in the CRM triggers a proc to update the DW server. So, I don't see how the DW server could be updating before the CRM server. You stated they are called simultaneously, but that would negate the comment about the trigger.  You wouldn't want the DW to get dirty reads, so READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT is a good choice here but you can also specify whatever isolation level you want at the transaction level and override the server default.

Since you asked *"Is there a way to wait for transaction to commit and then read the latest data after commitment?"*. Sure, this can be handled in a few ways...

- one would be a [AFTER INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) trigger
- another would be to add the `UPDATE` to the DW in a code block after the `INSERT` statement, in the same procedure. Here, you could use `TRY / CATCH` and of course, [SET XACT_ABORT ON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) so that if anything fails, the entire transaction is rolled back. Remember, [nested transaction aren't real.](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/)